# Sending image as response in ExpressJS results in empty response

Tags: node.js, express

Using ExpressJS and the `request-promise` module I download an image from a remote webservice. This image shall be sent to the caller.

```
function exportImage(req, res) {
    request({url: myUrl})
        .then(data => {
            res.contentType("image/png");
            res.send(data);
        });
}
```

When calling this function it returns an HTTP 200, `Content-Type` is set to "image/png" and the `Content-Length` seems to be correct.

However the response itself is empty, i.e. the browser neither shows the image nor offers it for download.

When am I missing here?

Comment: Could you show how `exportImage` is being called?

Comment: @dubonzi `exportImage` is the `operationId` defined in a Swagger YAML. There is no further code I wrote for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a "quick and dirty" solution I piped the original response like this:

```
function exportImage(req, res) {
    request({url: myUrl}).pipe(res);
}
```